# What is dbms_aw$_columnlist_t in plsql and what is its purpose?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, parameter-passing, procedure

I need to do some fixes in a plsql packge. In that package, I came across a procedure in plsql using dbms_aw$_columnlist_t. It has been used to declare parameters in that procedure.

```
procedure proc_test(p1 IN dbms_aw$_columnlist_t,
                    p2 IN dbms_aw$_columnlist_t,
                    p3 IN OUT dbms_aw$_columnlist_t,
                    p4 IN OUT dbms_aw$_columnlist_t
                   )
```

Can somebody please suggest what and how is this being used and also is this a new addition to oracle ?

Thank You!

Comment: If only Oracle published its documentation online, it would be easy to search for this. [Wait a minute....](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_app_dbms_aw.htm#BABGGHHI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a TABLE OF VARCHAR2 TYPE with the below format

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sys.dbms_aw$_columnlist_t
     AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

For more information refer this [article](https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_aw.html)